# App.ArticleAdapter =DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({}); extend undefined in ember js-Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i am new to emberjs. when i am trying to extend DS.FixtureAdapter i am getting error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined`
here is my

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ArticleAdapter =DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To ask a question which you can get answered, please visit: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ember Data 2.x, `FixtureAdapter` was moved to the [ember-data-fixture-adapter](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-data-fixture-adapter) addon.
Consult its README for install and usage instructions.